# How to assign indexes to variable names inside FOR LOOP?

Tags: javascript

How to assign indexes to variable names? For instance, project0, project1, project2, etc?

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
{
    var project+i = new GanttProjectInfo(1, "Applet redesign", new Date(2010, 5, 11));
    var parentTask+i = new GanttTaskInfo(1, "Old code review", new Date(2010, 5, 11), 208, 50, "");
    project1.addTask(parentTask+i);
    // Load data structure        
    ganttChartControl.addProject(project+i);
    // Build control on the page
}
```

Comment: Don't do it, use an array instead! (will save you from pain)

Comment: I agree with @Niko, do `arr.push(5 + i)`. `window["varname" + i] = ...` would work, but it's not very useful and pollutes the namespace. Outside of global, you'd use an object like `obj = {} ... obj['varname' + i] = ...`. Again, though, a bit pointless compared to an array in this case.

Comment: @Niko: I updated my example. The thing is that I'm creating Gantt chart using DHTMLX library. How to solve this problem with arrays?

Comment: `projects.push(new GanttProjectInfo(...));`

Comment: And how to tackle this: project1.addTask(parentTask+i);? Like this projects[i].addTask(parentTasks[i]);??

Comment: `var project = new GanttProjectInfo(...); var parentTask = new GanttTaskInfo(...); project.addTask(parentTask); projects.push(project);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as @JaredFarrish suggested, you can simply use an array to store all the projects. Create them and add them to the array before the variable gets overwritten:

```
var projects = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var project = new GanttProjectInfo(1, "Applet redesign", new Date(2010, 5, 11));
    var parentTask = new GanttTaskInfo(1, "Old code review", new Date(2010, 5, 11), 208, 50, "");
    project.addTask(parentTask);
    ganttChartControl.addProject(project);

    // Push this project to the array to save it
    projects.push(project);
}

// Need to access the first project?
projects[0].foo();
```

Comment: Wow, identical to the comment I was writing. +1 `:)`

Comment: Only improvement I'd suggest is storing `data.length` for the iteration context, ie, `i = 0, length = data.length, i < length...`

Answer (score 0):

using eval()

eval(("varname" + i) + " = " + 5 + i);

but using eval is not really recommended there is always a way around for what you are trying to do.